# IdentityServer3 overridden PostAuthenticateAsync method not called

Tags: identityserver3

We have a custom user service set up implementing UserServiceBase, overriding some methods (PreAuthenticateAsync, PostAuthenticateAsync, etc).  Our PreAuthenticateAsync method gets called when authenticating, but the PostAuthenticateAsync method never gets hit.

The user flow is such that a person with an expired password should get redirected to a reset page. PostAuthenticate seems like the best place to handle this after the user's Identity has been established (we have a custom claim for the expired field we can check here).

The method is overridden [public override Task PostAuthenticateAsync(PostAuthenticationContext context)], but I can't figure out why it doesn't get hit after logging in. Has anyone experienced this or can think of any reason why this might be happening? Or any thoughts an a better approach I should look into? Thanks!

Here's the relevant code parts:

```
public class MyAccountUserService : UserServiceBase
{
    public override Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        var id = _owinContext.Request.Query.Get("signin");
        context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("~/custom/login?id=" + id, (IEnumerable<Claim>)null);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public override Task PostAuthenticateAsync(PostAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        if (context.AuthenticateResult.User.Identity.GetIsExpiredPassword())
        {
            context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("/account/reset", (IEnumerable<Claim>)null);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
        else
        {
            return base.PostAuthenticateAsync(context);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your `UserService` code?

Comment: @Kahbazi, I can't add the entire class, but I added the relevant parts above.
A breakpoint on the PreAuthenticateAsync method gets hit during login, but PostAuthenticateAsync never gets hit.